# How to pass a .txt file as an argument for a function in a different cpp

Tags: c++, arguments

```
int main()
{
    fstream file;
    file.open("new_file.txt" , ios::app);
    if (!file.is_open()){
        cout << "File does not exist yet !\n";
        return 1;
    }
    string input;
    cout << "Add new line or edit? Write NEW or EDIT";
    cin >> input;
    if (input == "NEW")
    {
        add_new_info();
    }
    //.....
}
```

**In another cpp I have:**

```
int add_new_info()
{
    string aux;
    int count;
    cout << "Add line ID \n";
    cin >> aux;
    file << aux << "; ";
    //...
}
```

So basically I want to open the `txt` file in `main` and then pass it on to the `add_new_info()`. How do I pass a `txt file` as an argument to a function in another `.cpp` ?

Comment: Add parameter: `int add_new_info( std::ostream& stream )` then you can pass `file` as argument to that function, e. g. `add_new_info( file )`.

Comment: If you want to become a bad programmer, you might also turn `file` into a global (with a suitable `extern` declaration added in the other cpp file) ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I didn't fully understand what you meant. You mean changing the name "file"? I just translated it real quick because I had it in my language. It had a different name, if that's what you meant.

Comment: Good habit to learn: **fully initialize** every object when it's created. Instead of `std::fstream file; file.open("new_file.txt", std::ios::app);` use `std::fstream file("new_file.txt", std::ios::app);`.

Comment: @PeteBecker I see. Thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 2):

You can just pass a reference to the open file

```
int add_new_info(fstream& file)
{
    // add info to the file

}
```

and at the call in `main`

```
add_new_info(file);
```

---

And like zett42 mentions in the comments, if the function doesn't use anything specific to file streams, using a parameter `std::ostream&` would allow the use of the function for other types of streams as well, like `add_new_info(cout);` to display the info at the console.

Comment: That should be an `std::ostream&` to be more generic.

Comment: @zett42  - Sure, but if `fstream` works in `main` it also works for the parameter. Presumably there is a dreaded `using namespace std;` somewhere in the .cpp file.

Comment: Sure it will work, but why artificially restrict a function to take only *file* streams?

Comment: @zett - Ah, yes `ostream` would be more general. I thought you were looking for the `std::` prefix.

Comment: Works perfectly fine! Thank you very much.

Comment: @BoPersson I mean, if I have the function in the same .cpp file it works fine. However if I have a function in a different .cpp from the main, it doesn't work. I am using a header but still no good.

Comment: @N.Car - There should be no difference, as long as you have the function declaration `int add_new_info(std::fstream& file);` in the header and include that in the file where `main()` is.

Comment: @BoPerssoni forgot to had all the #include in the header file! It works now, thank you very much for your help.